# Why does query become very slow with multiple indexes even I don't use it

Tags: mysql, tidb

I am using TiDB to do some testing.

I created a table as below

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
 id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 updated BIGINT NOT NULL
)
```

I loaded around 100,000,000 rows into this table with 2 indexes

```sql
CREATE INDEX hash_index USING HASH ON users (id);
CREATE INDEX btree_index USING BTREE ON users (updated);
```

I found query speed became very slow, it would take a few seconds

Query sql is below. I only used the first index.

```sql
SELECT * FROM users where id=1999;
```

I solved this slow issue by deleting the second index `updated`

I thought second index cause this issue.

I was just wondering how it happened?

Comment: So re-creating that index slows down the query again?

Comment: Also, given that id is a PRIMARY KEY, I'm struggling to understand the point of the hash_index

Answer (score 0):

1. What's your TiDB version?
2. The id column in the USERS table is the primary key. The execution plan should Point_Get_1. I think the index should have no effect.

+-------------+---------+---------+------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+--------+------+
| id          | estRows | actRows | task | access object | execution info                                                 | operator info | memory | disk |
+-------------+---------+---------+------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+--------+------+
| Point_Get_1 | 1.00    | 1       | root | table:users   | time:1.302907ms, loops:2, Get:{num_rpc:1, total_time:1.2536ms} | handle:10     | N/A    | N/A  |
+-------------+---------+---------+------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+--------+------+

3. I think you could check "explain analyze SELECT * FROM users where id=1999;".
   Is the execution plan of the SQL same？